# is try-catch without finally the same as try-catch with finally?

Tags: exception, try-catch, finally

I really don't understand use of finally block...
in try-catch block, Whether we use finally or not we can get same run of our code.
for example what is difference between these code:

```
   try
   {
       System.out.println(1/0);
   }
   catch(ArithmeticException e)
   {
       System.out.println("Error");
   }
   finally
   {
       System.out.println("After try-catch");
   }
```

and this:

```
   try
   {
       System.out.println(1/0);
   }
   catch(ArithmeticException e)
   {
       System.out.println("Error");
   }

   System.out.println("After try-catch");
```

what is logically difference in output or hierarchy of running codes???

Answer (score 1):

A `finally` will *ALWAYS* execute, except in certain cases, such as a `System.exit()` call, or a thread abruptly exiting.

As always the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) defines all behaviours

Comment: also if i write my codes after catch without finally block, it will ALWAYS execute whether exception occurs or not!!

Comment: @Ahmad, not if the exception is thrown or a `RuntimeException` occurs.

Comment: what you mean "if the exception is thrown" ?? can tell me with an example?